# Problems with 2 databases (mySQL) in Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm having problems with making 2 databases in Django, I followed [official example], but when I try to start server I get Syntaxerror: invalid syntax (pointed to the settings.py file at vnosdatabase (see bellow).

What I'm trying to acchieve is to separate 'vnos' application from rest of the project and apps, with different database.

My relevant files look like this:

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'testdatabase',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'Xma47data',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
    },
'vnosdatabase': {       #not sure what to give here
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'vnosdatabase',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'Xma47data',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
    } 
}
DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['vnos.routers.vnosRouter',]  #routers.py located in vnos directory
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Cost(models.Model):
cost = models.FloatField()
amount = models.FloatField()

class Meta:
    app_label = 'vnos1'
```

routers.py

```
class vnosRouter(object):
"""
A router to control all database operations on models in the
vnos application.
"""
def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to read vnos models go to vnosdatabase.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'vnos1':
        return 'vnosdatabase'
    return None

def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
    """
    Attempts to write vnos models go to vnosdatabase.
    """
    if model._meta.app_label == 'vnos1':
        return 'vnosdatabase'
    return None

def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
    """
    Allow relations if a model in the vnos app is involved.
    """
    if obj1._meta.app_label == 'vnos1' or \
       obj2._meta.app_label == 'vnos1':
       return True
    return None

def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):
    """
    Make sure the auth app only appears in the 'vnosdatabase'
    database.
    """
    if app_label == 'vnos1':
        return db == 'vnosdatabase'
    return None
```

P.S: FIXED ALL THE PROBLEMS, will leave it here for future reference to everyone  who is trying for the first time to make multiple databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error because you are missing a comma:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'testdatabase',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'Xma47data',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
    },  # <-- HERE
'vnosdatabase': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'vnosdatabase',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'Xma47data',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
    'PORT': '3306',
    } 
}
```

If we run your original file without the comma we get an error like this:

```
  File "settings.py", line 10
    'vnosdatabase': {
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

To understand this message, you first want to find out what `SyntaxError` means. The [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.SyntaxError) don't really explain it clearly for newbies, [WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error) has a better description.

So we know already our problem is some invalid Python code - not a problem with databases or logic, just some code that the Python interpreter cannot understand.  Once you are confident in knowing and using the syntax of the language you are programming in, encountering a `SyntaxError` almost always means you've made a typo somewhere.

We also know in which file, and (roughly) where the typo is.

Now, unfortunately Python is unable to say *"You have a missing comma on line 9"* because there are various possible valid codes that could come after line 9 with no comma. You could close the dict there with a `}` for example.

Instead, Python shows what it *did* find next - the string `'vnosdatabase'` on line 10 - which Python points to and says "invalid syntax", i.e. *this can't appear here*.

So then, if you think that code is correct, you need to look backwards from there to find where you have a typo preventing Python from interpreting your code.

Comment: I am a bit of newbie in programming so I never even thought about checking the line above the stated line, thus I missed this error, I appreciate your help :)

Comment: No problem, it's always easy to miss these little details! I wanted to make the point that it's very useful to learn interpret the error message, the "stack trace", that Python displays when an exception occurs... I've added some more info to the answer about how to do this.